# Пост записи на стену с URL картинки в Android с использованием VK SDK

Tags: android, java, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

```
api.createWallPost(USER_ID, message,  null, null, false, false, false, null, null, new Long(0), new Long(0), null, null);
```

Я исользую данный метод для размещения поста на стене `USER_ID`( текст записи - message). Можно ли как то сделать чтобы скажем в message добавлял ЮРЛ картинки, и на записи автоматически отображалась картинка? Ведь когда в ручную на сайте вк создаешь запись и вставляешь URL картинки, то изображение автоматически заливается на сайт

https://github.com/ruxman/Android-VK-SDK